# count records is not giving the right number

Tags: mysql

When I type the following query

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM
    OP_table OP
WHERE
    OP.TARGET_ID= 4330000000000369;
```

I get a count of 55

When I try to use it in a join

```
SELECT
    TS.TARGET_ID, T.TARGET_NAME, T.TARGET_PUBLIC_NAME, count( DISTINCT OP.OP_ID) AS OP_COUNT
FROM
    TS_table TS
INNER jOIN
     T_table T
ON
    T.TARGET_ID = TS.TARGET_ID
OUTER JOIN
    OP_TABLE OP
ON
    OP.TARGET_ID = T.TARGET_ID
WHERE
    TS.TARGET_SERVICE_ID = number
```

Then I get

```
TARGET_ID,    TARGET_NAME,    TARGET_PUBLIC_NAME,    OP_COUNT
number,       target name,    Ebook Central History  33781
```

with an count of 33781. I want to use the 2nd functions structure but get the right count of 55

for some reason it's getting the count of the Target_id's instead of Target_service ID's

also I noticed if I type the following

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM
    KB_OBJECT_PORTFOLIOS OP
WHERE
    OP.TARGET_ID=4330000000000383;
```

where that number corresponds will produce the result 33781.

somewhere within the joining it's getting rid of the target ID of 4330000000000369 and using a different target ID 4330000000000383

Comment: I think your inner join WHERE should be `WHERE
    OP.TARGET_ID= 4330000000000369` instead off `WHERE
    TS.TARGET_SERVICE_ID = number`

Comment: The above query would yield a syntax error only, since you do not specify whether your outer query is left or right.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I get mixed up from the stupid column names OP.target_ID = TS.target_service_id and not TS.target_ID...